# Why is hist2d plotting UNIFORM density map?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, heatmap, density-plot

I am plotting density map of ~40k points but hist2d returns a uniform density map. This is my code

```
hist2d(x, y, bins=(1000, 1000), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
```

Here is the scatter plot
[image]

Here is the histogram
[image]

I was expecting that there is a red horizontal portion in the center and the gradually turns blue towards  higher/lower y values

EDIT:
[@bb1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15187728/bb1) suggested decrease the number of bins but by setting it to `bins=(100, 1000)`, I get this result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are specifying too many bins. By setting `bins=(1000,000)` you get 1,000,000 bins. With 40,000 points, most of the bins will be empty and they overwhelm the image.

You may also consider using seaborn `kdeplot()` function instead of `plt.hist2d()`. It will visualize the density of data without subdividing data into bins:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y, levels = 100, fill=True, cmap="mako", thresh=0)
```

Comment: It is taking forever to generate the plot. Maybe I have too many dots? I am using the same parameters as you had here.